# Execute a javascript line in Splash (Scrapy)

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I want to execute a single line of javascript in Splash for pagination. Is there a way to execute the JS multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can not run JavaScript exactly but there is a scripting language called lua which is similar to JavaScript, no major syntactical difference is there between them.

You can refer to https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-tutorial.html

Or if i have misinterpreted then please be more specific.